# Mapping an array in NHibernate

Tags: c#, arrays, hibernate, nhibernate, dictionary

I've got an array in a single column in my database. 
In postgres it looks like this:

```
orientation double precision[]
```

where 'orientation' is column name.
How to map this in C#?

`< property name="Orientation"/>` in my hbm.xml file doesn't do the work. 
My class in C# contains the field:

```
public virtual double[] Orientation { get; set; }
```

This gives me an exception:

> Could not cast the value in field Orientat9_0_ of type Double[] to the
>   Type SerializableType.  Please check to make sure that the mapping is
>   correct and that your DataProvider supports this Data Type.

And also this:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double[]' to type
>   'System.Byte[]'.

I don't want to create any additional tables in my database.

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746414/how-configure-nhibernate-to-map-to-an-array-if-there-is-no-index-in-the-table

Answer (score 0):

You will need to code your own `IUserType` to handle this.

Comment: I tried and tried but failed to do so. Can you provide some code for this? This is what i narrowed it down to (note that my array always contains 6 elements):
     http://pastebay.net/1149297